# Switching user roles in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

I am switching my Snowflake roles in my account console but, in my worksheet context, the role doesn't automatically reflect. Do I need to change this in both the places all the time?

Comment: When you say "in my account console" do you mean the drop-down box on the top right of your screen on the web-ui? If this is what you mean, then that box only set your role for the outer web UI frame and not the role that is used when executing SQL queries.

Comment: thank you , that solves it ! I wanted to be sure that it is designed that way and that I am not seeing it differently !

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you switch your role from A to B in the upper right corner and you want to execute the query with role B. In this case you also have to switch the role in the worksheet to B.

The role on your worksheet-level "overwrites" the role in your upper right corner.

You can change the role on the worksheet-level by using the GUI or executing `USE ROLE xy;`.

Comment: thank you , that solves it ! I wanted to be sure that it is designed that way and that I am not seeing it differently !

Answer (score 0):

The role mentioned under your username on the top right-hand corner is for the option available to the left of the same console. This is totally independent of the role selected in each worksheet.
for example, For accountadmin role - you would able to see an additional option like Account, which will not be able with PUBLIC role. You can try to switch between the roles.

The role selected in the worksheet defines your access privileges on the database objects. The SQL statements executed are evaluated with the worksheet role.

You can user properties such as Default_role, Default_warehosue & default_namespace(db &schema). Details [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html#usage-notes)

This will help to get your user context set with the defaults on every new worksheet created.

Comment: thank you , that solves it ! I wanted to be sure that it is designed that way and that I am not seeing it differently !